# Ubuntu Touch and installing .click packages outside of Ubuntu app store?

Tags: ubuntu-touch

I have just gotten my hands on an E5 Ubuntu Touch device, however, I don't want to register anywhere (including the Ubuntu app store) until I get the hang of it.

Now, I'm aware that on Android, the app store packages have an extension `.apk`, and they can be installed either through the Google Play store with a proper login, or through a USB connection using `adb install *.apk`.

I've learned that on Ubuntu, the [format defined for Ubuntu Touch is called "Click," using the .click file extension](https://lwn.net/Articles/565521/), and it can also be installed either through the Ubuntu app store, or through a USB connection using [`pkcon install-local --allow-untrusted *.click`](http://daniel-beck.org/howto-install-click-packages/).

However, I'm also aware that on Android, you can start a download of an `.apk` file, and then install it by doubleclicking (or its equivalent in tapping) once its downloaded; can Ubuntu Touch do the same?

If it can, is there an example online of a very simple `.click` application, that I could download and install the same way - possibly by allowing some developer options first?

I've noticed via [Touch/Collection - Ubuntu Wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Collection), say, the [xkcd-viewer](https://launchpad.net/~hansueli-burri/+archive/ubuntu/xkcd-viewer) app - but all it offers for download are `.deb` files, which apparently don't install on Ubuntu Touch, at least not through the GUI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not fully clear of the question. You wanna know if click packages are able to install without the Ubuntu store?
If that is the question, then the answer is yes.

You need the click file. In the terminal you can install it on the device.

Comment: Thanks @JOnathanJOnes - I already wrote that I'm aware that I can install through the terminal on Desktop. What I also want to know is - can I install .click files via download link, and where can I find a download link with an actual .click file for testing?

Comment: https://open.uappexplorer.com/api/download/openstore.openstore-team/openstore.openstore-team_0.98_armhf.click should be a click package. As far as I know, there is no way to download and install click packages in one action via snap yet.

Comment: Fantastic, @JOnathanJOnes - that was the info I was looking for; many thanks!